# Setting environment variable to /urs/local - basemap installation

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to download Basemap to use its functions based on this link: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html

I have followed everything they say until this part of the installation: **if libgeos_c is in /usr/local/lib and geos_c.h is in /usr/local/include, set GEOS_DIR to /usr/local**

The goal for this step is to set the environment variable GEOS_DIR to point to the location /usr/local.

However, I am not sure how to set an environment variable to point to a certain location. I looked at other answers saying I need to create a plist, but I don't know much about it. I'm using MacOS mojave :)

Answer (score 0):

you can list your environment variables with the bash command:

```
printenv
```

You can set an environment variable temporarily with

```
export some_variable=some_directory
```

here is a link with more information: `https://medium.com/@youngstone89/setting-up-environment-variables-in-mac-os-28e5941c771c`.